# Ignore SVG aspect ratio and stretch to 100% window size

Tags: html, css, svg, background-image

I have a svg file that a am using as a `background-image`. Now I would like to stretch it to the size of the window. **All aspect ratios should be ignored**, so the background SVG should neither use `background-size: cover` nor `contain`.

Right now I have this code, but it doesn't work.

```
html {
  background: url("image.svg") center no-repeat;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}
```

Does someone have any idea?

Comment: What do you mean by "All aspect ratios should be ignored"?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can simply add `preserveAspectRatio="none"` to SVG if you don't care about aspect ratio. And set`background-size: 100% 100%;` in the CSS.

Example:

```css
html {
  background: url("data:image/svg+xml,%3Csvg xmlns='http://www.w3.org/2000/svg' preserveAspectRatio='none' width='24' height='24' viewBox='0 0 24 24'%3E%3Cpath d='M12,17.27L18.18,21L16.54,13.97L22,9.24L14.81,8.62L12,2L9.19,8.62L2,9.24L7.45,13.97L5.82,21L12,17.27Z'%3E%3C/path%3E%3C/svg%3E") center / 100% 100% no-repeat;
  height: 100%;
}
```

Comment: works like a charm, thank you!

Comment: You are my life saver